# Project Reactor: possibly misleading documentation about error handling

Tags: spring, project-reactor

I am reading Reactor reference documentation about error handling and something seems wrong. For example this section about [fallback method](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#_fallback_method):

```
Flux.just("key1", "key2")
    .flatMap(k -> callExternalService(k)) 
    .onErrorResume(e -> getFromCache(k));
```

But `onErrorResume()` lambda takes only one parameter `e` (error throwable). How `k` (previous value emitted by flux) is referenced here?

There are other similar code snippets in the docs. Am I reading this wrong?
Or if documentation is indeed incorrect how can I actually handle this case: recover from error by executing alternative path with previous value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think you found a bug in the documentation.

If you want to use `k` the call to `onErrorResume` must happen inside the argument to `flatMap` like so:

```
Flux.just("key1", "key2")
    .flatMap(k -> callExternalService(k)
            .onErrorResume(e -> getFromCache(k))
    );
```

Regarding your comment: It is not possible to have the value being processed as part of the `onErrorXXX` methods because the error in question might not be happening while a value was processed. Maybe it happened for example while handling backpressure (i.e. requestion more elements) or while subscribing.

Comment: Thanks @Jens. It'll be nice to have access to both exception and previous value in onErrorResume() and onErrorReturn() methods though.

Comment: updated the answer to explain why you can't have the current value in the error message.